# Get PHP folder listing without directories

Tags: php

when the url parameter is set than it should search if there is a folder with this parametername/foldername. 
but the glob function gives me the directory and foldername.
How can i listing the foldername without the directories ?

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET["customer"])){
    $customer = $_GET['customer'];
    $path = 'cover/';
    $dirs = glob($path.'*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    print_r($dirs);
    if(array_search($customer, $dirs) !== false) {
        echo "found something";
    }
    else {
        echo "nothing found";
    }
}
else {
    echo "no parameter in the url";
}

?>
```

the result of this code:

```
Array ( [0] => cover/twDE [1] => cover/twEN )
```

so i would like to have an array just with the foldernames without cover/...

thank you for your help
Greg

Comment: You need to clean your array (*via `array_map()` & `str_replace("cover/","",$theelement);`.*) and then run your comparison. Or you could change your array search to `array_search($path . $customer, $dirs)....`

Comment: thank you that helps me a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
$dirs = glob($path.'*', GLOB_ONLYDIR); // get all folders/directories
// loop in folders array
foreach ($dirs as $key => $val) {
    // cut "cover/" string from paths
    $dirs[$key] = str_replace("cover/", "", $val);
}
// check is folder with name "folderName" exists in array
if (in_array("folderName", $dirs)) {
    echo "Exists";
}
```

Comment: Please add a brief explanation of what your code does. It is pretty straightforward but it will be more useful for other devs, as reference.

Comment: I have serveral customer covers for a pageflip magazine.The main content of the magazine is the same. If the customer gives us a cover than he can access his own cover via the url parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function customResult($dirsFound) {
    return str_replace('cover/', '', $dirsFound);
}

$customer = isset($_GET['customer']) ? $_GET['customer'] : '';
if (strlen($customer)) {
    $path = 'cover/';
    $dirs = array_map('customResult', glob($path . '*', GLOB_ONLYDIR));

    if (array_search($customer, $dirs) !== false) {
        echo "found something";
    } else {
        echo "nothing found";
    }
} else {
    echo "no parameter in the url";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to do it.

With `chdir` and `scandir`:

```
chdir('./cover');
$dirs = array_filter(scandir('.'), 'is_dir'));
```

With `FilesystemIterator`:

```
$fsi = new FileSystemIterator('./cover');
foreach ($fsi as $element) {
    if ($element->isDir()) {
        echo $element->getbasename(), PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Or with `glob` and `basename`:

```
print_r(array_map('basename', glob('./cover', GLOB_ONLYDIR)));
```

All of the above would give you just the directory names within the "cover" folder. You can then run your `array_search` or whatever else on it.

**But:** since your folder names seem to correspond to your customer names, you can just as well `glob` for them directly, e.g.

```
glob("./cover/$customer", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
```

This would save you the additional call to `in_array`. If the result is an empty array, there is no customer directory.

With that said, you can reduce your code to a single check if you just  verify whether the path + customer value is a directory e.g.

```
if (is_dir("./cover/$customer")) {
    // found your customer's folder
}
```

On a side note: if you use this approach, you should make sure the `$customer` variable does not contain characters that allow directory traversal to prevent malicious users from trying to map your filesystem layout.